# How to create REST micros-service using Apache Camel and Jetty

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I have been experimenting with Apache Camel for creating a REST based micro services. Based on my experiments this is how I created an echo service with Jetty:

### Maven

Included the following dependency in the Maven build:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

### Java

Created a small route in Java which gets a request, converts it to a string, saves it to a file and then sends it back to the client:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class EchoHttpServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("jetty://http://localhost:8099/echo?httpMethodRestrict=POST")
                        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                        .to("file://D:/work")
                        .process(exchange -> exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody()));
            }
        });
        context.start();
    }
}
```

### Integration Test

This can then be tested using the Chrome extension Postman with which you can send a POST request which is then echoed by the reply:

[image]

Is this the recommended way to create REST based services with Apache Camel? Which are the potential problems of the approach taken above?

Comment: If you want to create REST based services with Camel I'd suggest looking at the Camel Rest DSL: http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html

Comment: I am currently creating a Camel-based pseudo-REST service for internal evaluation. It uses Camel's REST DSL in combination with Jetty and certain other techniques like JSON HAL support, Spring Security, Amazon XRay and Mongo Views. If you are interested you can [check out the Github repo](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security). Note however, that this is more of a tech-demo than an actual full-fledged API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways how to expose a REST services with Camel.

Pure servet - this is what you already did. Seems to be quick and simple way (maybe too simple).

REST Camel endpoints  (thanks noMad) http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html

In a container with a framework. My favourite is [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) with [Camel-CXF](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html) . It takes more time to start, more memory to run, but frameworks allow additional features, such as authentication, auhtorization, logging, ..

If someone finds another way, please add an answer or comment, I am keen to find new options as well

Comment: As you asked for a hint: Camel's REST DSL ^^

Comment: If you are keen to find new options as well, why not upvote the question? :)